# Polynomial regression using scikit-learn

Tags: regression, machine-learning, large-data, polynomial, scikit-learn

I am trying to use scikit-learn for polynomial regression. From what I read polynomial regression is a special case of linear regression. I was hopping that maybe one of scikit's generalized linear models can be parameterised to fit higher order polynomials but I see no option for doing that.

I did manage to use a Support Vector Regressor with a poly kernel. That worked well with a subset of my data, but it takes much to long to fit larger data sets so I still need to find something faster (even if trading some precision).

Am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Given data $\mathbf{x}$, a column vector, and $\mathbf{y}$, the target vector, you can perform polynomial regression by appending polynomials of $\mathbf{x}$. For example, consider if

$$ \mathbf{x} = \begin{bmatrix}
       2    \\[0.3em]
       -1 \\[0.3em]
       \frac{1}{3}         
     \end{bmatrix}$$

Using just this vector in linear regression implies the model:

$$ y = \alpha_1 x $$

We can add columns that are powers of the vector above, which represent adding polynomials to the regression. Below we show this for polynomials up to power 3:
$$
X = \begin{bmatrix}
       2 & 4 & 8          \\[0.3em]
       -1 & 1           & -1 \\[0.3em]
       \frac{1}{3}        & \frac{1}{3^2} & \frac{1}{3^3}
     \end{bmatrix}$$

This is our new data matrix that we use in sklearn's linear regression, and it represents the model:

$$ y = \alpha_1 x + \alpha_2x^2 + \alpha_3x^3$$

---

Note that I did not add a constant vector of $1$'s, as sklearn will automatically include this.

Answer (score 43):

**Theory**

Polynomial regression is a special case of linear regression. With the main idea of how do you select your features. Looking at the multivariate regression with 2 variables: `x1` and `x2`. Linear regression will look like this: `y = a1 * x1 + a2 * x2.`

Now you want to have a polynomial regression (let's make 2 degree polynomial). We will create a few additional features: `x1*x2`, `x1^2` and `x2^2`. So we will get your 'linear regression':

```
y = a1 * x1 + a2 * x2 + a3 * x1*x2 + a4 * x1^2 + a5 * x2^2
```

This nicely shows an important concept [curse of dimensionality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_dimensionality), because the number of new features grows much faster than linearly with the growth of degree of polynomial.

**Practice with scikit-learn**

You do not need to do all this in scikit. [Polynomial regression](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#polynomial-regression-extending-linear-models-with-basis-functions) is already available there (in **0.15** version. Check [how to update it here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22914458/1090562)).

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn import linear_model

X = [[0.44, 0.68], [0.99, 0.23]]
vector = [109.85, 155.72]
predict= [[0.49, 0.18]]
#Edit: added second square bracket above to fix the ValueError problem

poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2)
X_ = poly.fit_transform(X)
predict_ = poly.fit_transform(predict)

clf = linear_model.LinearRegression()
clf.fit(X_, vector)
print clf.predict(predict_)
```

Comment: What if I do not want to have an interaction terms as x1*x2, do i have to construct X_ manually? there's a parameter "interaction_only" in PolynomialFeatures() constructor, and by default it is False. But setting it to True makes the opposite of what i want: it keeps ONLY the interaction terms, and do not keep x1^2, x2^2, etc.

Comment: The link to youtube claims that the video does not exist anymore. Do you have any other link to that?

Comment: @Markon any video from this list is good enough: https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=curse+of+dimensionality

Comment: @SalvadorDali that is what dimensionality reduction is for

Comment: I wonder if we should center the data before or after applying `PolynomialFeatures` ?

Comment: ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[0.49 0.18].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.

Comment: I also get a ValueError.. this code does not work (anymore)

Answer (score 3):

In case you are using a multivariate regression and not just a univariate regression, do not forget the cross terms. For instance if you have two variables $x_1$ and $x_2$, and you want polynomials up to power 2, you should use $y = a_1x_1 + a_2x_2 + a_3x_1^2 + a_4x_2^2 + a_5x_1x_2$ where the last term ($a_5x_1x_2$) is the one I am talking about.

Answer (score 1):

Using a similar approach to @Cam.Davidson.Pilon, I wrote a couple functions to help demo this approach in Python. It can be expanded by adding more terms in the `np.concatenate` vectors. The output for the `y_pred` would not change, but getting the coefficients, `regr.coef_[0][2]`, would need to be included.

```
from sklearn import linear_model
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
def regress_2nd_order(x, y):
    # The x values are transformed into the second order matrix
    X = np.concatenate([x, x**2], axis=1)
    # Use model to fit to the data 
    regr.fit(X, y)
    # Extract the values of interest for forming the equation...
    # y_pred = c0 + c1 * x + c2 * x^2 
    c0 = round(regr.intercept_[0],2)
    c1 = round(regr.coef_[0][0],2)
    c2 = round(regr.coef_[0][1],4)
    # c3 = round(regr.coef_[0][2],4)
    # Another way to get this is using the `regr.predict` function
    # Predict will calculate the values for you
    y_pred = regr.predict(X)
    # Print the intercept (c0) and the corresponding coefficients
    print('Scikit learn - \nEquation: %.2f + %.2f*T + %.5f*T^2' % (c0,c1,c2) )
    #  return y_pred, (c0, c1, c2, c3)
    return y_pred, (c0, c1, c2)
def socket_temp(x, y):
    # Include only the predicted y-vector
    y_pred = regress_2nd_order(x, y)[0]
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(10,10))
    ax.plot(x, y_pred, ls='', marker='*', label='predicted')
    ax.plot(x, y, ls='', marker='.', label='iddt')
    ax.legend()
```

For my use, I had temperature as my `y` variable, and a dynamic supply current (IDDT) output as my `x` variable. Here are the values I used for `x` and `y` and the output vector, `y_pred`:

```
    'iddt'  'temp'  'y_pred'
0   627.23  20.0    20.42
1   627.38  19.9    20.52
2   612.39  9.7     10.32
3   612.48  9.7     10.38
4   597.73  -0.1    0.19
5   597.78  -0.2    0.22
6   583.24  -10.1   -9.99
7   583.24  -10.0   -9.99
8   569.22  -19.9   -19.99
9   568.97  -19.9   -20.17
10  555.62  -29.8   -29.83
11  555.99  -29.8   -29.56
12  541.15  -40.1   -40.45
13  541.50  -40.1   -40.19
14  639.88  30.3    28.89
15  640.11  30.2    29.05
16  656.61  40.2    39.92
17  656.62  40.3    39.92
18  672.73  50.4    50.33
19  672.68  50.4    50.30
20  689.56  60.6    61.01
21  689.26  60.6    60.82
22  705.30  70.8    70.79
23  705.22  70.8    70.75
24  722.27  81.0    81.14
25  722.24  81.0    81.12
```

[image: Temp v IDDT]