# Can I still use Linear Regression assumptions test on a linear model with a Polynomial variable

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression, linear-model, nonlinear-regression

I have a multivariate linear model (y=x1+x2) which gives me the following results when using R's `plot()` function:
[image]

I can clearly see that the Normality and Linearity assumptions are not the best. Thus, I decided to add a 2nd degree polynomial variable to the model using `poly()` (which should give me a model such as y=x1^2+x1+x2) and got the following results:
[image]

I clearly see an improvement in both assumptions, however, that made me think: can I even do these two tests after I included the polynomial variable? Is the model still considered linear?

Comment: I am not well versed in R's specifics w.r.t. `poly()`, but assuming it adds a term that is polynomial in the _data_, you should be fine. A linear model is linear in the _parameters_, not necessarily in the _data_.

Comment: poly() is used on the model itself, e.i: y~poly(x1,2)+x2. The data stays untouched.

Comment: So does it mean that I can't use the plots?

Comment: Yes, the model is still linear (in its parameters and that's what is important here). Yes, you can use these plots.

Comment: Cool! Can you please explain when it won't longer be considered linear then? Because right now I am confused.

Comment: The term "linear" here has two meanings. One is that the model is a straight line. The other is that linear algebra can directly be used to solve for the coefficients in a technique named "linear regression". One is the name of a mathematical model, one is the name of a mathematical technique.

Comment: A linear regression model is defined as $\mathbf{y} = X\boldsymbol\beta + \boldsymbol\varepsilon$ where $X$ is the design matrix (all your x-variables) and $\boldsymbol\beta$ is the parameter vector. In the design matrix, a column can be squared values of another column, it won't change this basic, linear model. (Note that `poly` by default creates orthogonal polynomials.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the model still considered linear

To answer your question, recall the definition of a [linear model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression).

Given a dataset composed of a vector $\mathbf{x} = \{ x_1, x_2,...,x_n\}$ of $n$ explanatory variables and one dependent variable $y$ we assume in this model that the relationship between $\mathbf{x}$ and $y$ is **linear**

$$ y = \beta_0 1 + \beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 x_2 + ... + \beta_n x_n + \epsilon$$

Where $\beta_0$ is an intercept term and $\epsilon$ is the error variable, an unobserved random variable that adds "noise" to the linear relationship.

As @Roland points out, the linear relationship must hold in the *parameters*, not necessarily in the *data*. So nothing stops you from taking functions of the explanatory variables, and then performing the linear regression again. For example in your case, you could let:

$$ z_1 = x_1, \ z_2 = x_2, \ z_3 = x_1^2, \ z_4 = x_2^2$$

And then perform linear regression on $z$ as:

$$ y = \beta_0 1 + \beta_1 z_1 + \beta_2 z_2 + \beta_3 z_3 + \beta_4 z_4 + \epsilon $$
which is equivalent to

$$ y = \beta_0 1 + \beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 x_2 + \beta_3 x_1^2 + \beta_4 x_2^2 + \epsilon$$

> I clearly see an improvement in both assumptions

If your data shows signs of an underlying **polynomial** relationship between the explanatory variables, then fitting a linear regression model on polynomial variables will improve your model. As always, this comes with many advantages and disadvantages, some discussed in the posts linked below.

#### An example

Here is a toy example of trying to fit a linear regression model on a noisy sine curve. As you may know, the sine curve can be approximated by a [sum of polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series), so intuitively we would expect a polynomial linear regression model to do well under certain conditions:

[image]

#### More details

See these excellent posts for more details and explanations

- [Why is polynomial regression considered a special case of multiple linear regression?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/92065/why-is-polynomial-regression-considered-a-special-case-of-multiple-linear-regres/92087#92087)
- [Does it make sense to add a quadratic term but not the linear term to a model?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/28730/does-it-make-sense-to-add-a-quadratic-term-but-not-the-linear-term-to-a-model)
- [Polynomial regression using scikit-learn](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/58739/polynomial-regression-using-scikit-learn)